# File transfer via xRDP, Windows <=> Linux

Tags: linux, windows, file-copy, xrdp, x11vnc

#### Setup

We currently have up and running the following setup:

```
"Windows PC"  | "Linux PC"
-----------   | ----------
              |
RDP-Client ===|==> [xRDP] ==> [X11VNC] ==> [X11 Console Session]
              |
              |
```

Important is here that an RDP clients connects to the already running X11 session of a logged in user, instead of starting its own session.

#### New Requirement

Now the Customer *needs and must have* file transfer via RDP (Cut & Paste or Drag & Drop) from Windows machines to/from the Linux box.

For various reasons the Customer cannot use

- WinSCP
- A Samba share on the Linux machine
- Scripts, as it is not known in advance which files to transfer (mostly these will be logs and template files)
- Any other Tool that needs to be installed on the Windows machines

#### Question

Could you imagine a way where it would be possible to copy files to/from the Linux machine in a way one is accustomed to in the Windows world, i.e just throw some files onto his RDP client?

I read about `xrdp-chansrv`, `xrdp-sesman` and the ability of `xRDP` to do "Device Redirection", but I think

- there will be created a new X11 session on every connect
- the Linux desktop environment must be aware of this kind of file transfer (in normal operation we have only i3 running)
- it would interfere with the use of x11vnc

Comment: You could write a short PowerShell script which sends data over a TCP socket, and setup a netcat listener on the linux box. This doesn't require any additional software

Comment: @dcom-launch thank you for your effort. But this would require to know which files are needed and unfortunately it is not end-user compatible.